# Keeping my JS decoupled but still use functionality

Tags: javascript

In the very simple code below I'm illustrating having a master 'App' object with 'Chat' & 'Posts' modules inside.

Now, what I'm asking is, in my conscious effort to keep my components loosely coupled and modular, how I can use other functionality in the App object following the modular, decoupled pattern of JS web apps? I.e. imagine if I plucked the 'Chat' object out of the 'App' object and put it inside an 'App1' object, this code would break, so it's tightly coupled with the 'App' object.

Can anyone offer any advice on decoupling my code below?

```
​var App = {
    Utils: {
        add: function(a,b){
            return a + b;        
        }        
    },
    Posts: {

    },
    Chat: {
        init: function(){
            console.log(App.Utils.add(1,2)); // 3           
        },

    }
}

App.Chat.init();
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, your code wouldn't break as long as `App.Utils.add()` is still around to be called - even if `App.Chat.init()` becomes `SomethingElse.Chat.init()`. Of course, if you completely remove `App.Utils.add()` then, yeah, it'll break.

However, that can really be said of anything. You rely on `console.log()` too. If that goes away, your code will break.

Point is, your code will inevitably depend on *something*, so the question then becomes structure: Avoid having low-level functionality depend on higher-level functionality. And your structure is fine in this case. Yes, `App.Chat.init()` depends on `App.Utils.add()`, but that function doesn't depend on anything. It certainly doesn't depend on `App.Chat.init()` existing.

Take, for instance, jQuery or underscore.js. You code may well depend on one or both of those libraries, but they don't depend on your code. Structure your own code similarly: Keep `App.Utils` generic and low-level (as its name implies), but don't worry about other, higher-level, parts depending on it. Just make sure to include `App.Utils` if you plan to reuse things that depend on it. Generally speaking the more high-level a chunk of code is, the more dependencies it'll have.

All in all, I think you may be confusing namespacing with coupling. You're using `App` as your namespace, and putting everything in there. This does not mean the the "contents" of `App` are automatically coupled to each other.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a method on an object that you wish to use on another object, then perhaps [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) is for you.

```js
var App = {
    Utils: {
        add: function(a,b){
            return a + b;
        }
    },
    Posts: {

    },
    Chat: {
        init: function(){
            console.log(App.Utils.add(1,2)); // 3
        },

    }
}
var App1 = Object.create(App).prototype = {
    // Utils is not repeated, we just override the Chat.init method
    Chat: {
        init: function(){
            console.log(App.Utils.add(2,2), "<-- Chat has been decoupled"); // 4
        },

    }
};

App.Chat.init();

App1.Chat.init();  "<-- Chat has been decoupled"
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, your first answer looks good, if a bit short on the explanation - n.b. the question looked off-topic to me anyway, sorry about. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: Please refrain from answering off-topic questions. It's considered bad form and potentially motivates users to post more off-topic questions ("we get answers anyway, so why follow the rules?"). Find more information in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Don't worry about it in this case though, the question was quite old and not obviously off-topic to new users ;-)